# Resize OS X windows from any corner?

Tags: macos, window

Is there a way to resize windows on the Mac from corners other than the bottom right? I generally work tiled and with multiple monitors, and it's often very very frustrating to have to use the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 3):

OS X Lion has this ability, so you could upgrade. Also, [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) can provide this function.

See more over at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11490/edge-resizing-on-mac-finder-windows).